# Как можно на си распарсить строку содержащею в себе названия и расширения 'Hello.txt'?

Tags: c, строки

Нужно распарсить строку на си типа "Hello.txt" разделить на "Hello" и "txt". Есть какие средства на си для этого?

Comment: Ищите последнюю точку - например, идя с конца. Вот и распарсили...

Comment: В средствах си есть что-то для работы с парсирами ?

Comment: Смотря что вы под этим понимаете... И под "парсирами", и под "средствами" - например, стандартный С или какие-то сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Стандартный си. Сторонние библиотеки не все подходят.

Comment: Тогда берете и пишете сами, в чем проблема? На си создание велосипедов вполне приветствуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там писать нечего...

```
char filename[] = "Hello, world.txt";
char name[100] = {0}, ext[100] = {0};
char * dot = strrchr(filename,'.');
if (dot)
{
    strcpy(ext,dot+1);
    *dot = 0;
}
strcpy(name,filename);

printf("Name: \"%s\", ext: \"%s\"\n",name,ext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для задачи разбиения на лексемы рекомендуют функции `strtok_r` (POSIX) или `strtok_s` (MSVC). Есть еще не потокобезопасная функция `strtok`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char input[] = "Hello.txt";
    const char *delim = ".";
    char *token;
    char *next_token;

    token = strtok_r(input, delim, &next_token);
    while(token) {
        puts(token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &next_token);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Дополнительно рекомендую почитать книгу Бен Клеменс — Язык C в XXI веке, страница 199, песнь о strtok.